# How to add legend to ggplot loadings plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

So created a loadings plot via arrow style using ggplot command. In order to make things easier for graphing, I added a column into the dataframe of my rr.pr$rotation code with colours so that it graphs those arrows based on the colour I specified. The colours that match the arrows are important which is why I did it that way. I am having trouble now adding a legend as ggplot isn't adding a legend. 
Is there a way to add one or do I have to do something to the dataframe?

I was thinking of adding the colours manually, but I am getting stuck.

Green represents Sulfated, Orange represents Sialyllated, and Brown represents Neutral. And I would like the legend to show that.

Here is the code:

Dataframe

```
rrload<-data.frame(rr.pr$rotation[c(2,15,17,24,52),c(1:5)])
rrload$class<-c('orange','springgreen3','bisque3','bisque3','bisque3')
rrload1<-rrload[,c(1:5)]
rrload1<-as.numeric(as.matrix(rrload1))
rrload1<-matrix(rrload1,nrow=5,ncol=5,byrow = F)
rrload[,c(1:5)]<-rrload1
```

Code for plotting it:

```
ggplot(rrload)+geom_segment(aes(xend=PC1,yend=PC2),x=0,y=0,arrow = arrowstyle2,color=rrload$class)+
geom_text(aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,label=row.names(rrload)),hjust=0,nudge_x = -0.05,vjust=1,nudge_y = 0.025,size=3.5,color='black')+xlim(-0.3,0.3)+ylim(-0.3,0.3)+theme_light()+
theme_minimal()+theme(legend.title = element_text("Class"),axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black",size = 10),axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black",size = 10),axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black",size = 10),axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "black",size = 10),axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black"),panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black",fill = NA,size = 1))+geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype="dashed",color="gray69")+geom_vline(xintercept = 0,linetype="dashed",color="gray69")
```

This is the graph:

[Loadings plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbBnS.png)

Comment: Legends are created when specifying arguments within the `aes` mapping.  Also it is bad form to use hard-coded elements such as `rrload$class` and `row.names(rrload)`.  Can't type up a formal answer now, but might be able to later tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to your full data (your code is unable to recreate the dataframe, `rrload` properly), it's hard to help.  I managed to estimate the numbers based on the plot you shared.  Here's the dataframe I used - note the naming conventions for the columns:

```
d <- data.frame(
  PC1=c(-0.2,-0.2,0.1,0.15,-0.08),
  PC2=c(0.13,-0.1,0.2,0.1,-0.2300),
  class=c('Neutral','Neutral','Neutral','Sulfated','Silylated'),
  name=c('o53','o18','o25','o15','o2')
)
```

To prepare the data for plotting, I included `d$name` and `d$class`.  `d$class` is similar to the column you had, although instead of the color, I'm using the actual name.  `d$name` is the name that I'm using to plot your labels.

Here's the code I used and resulting plot.  Explanation will come after:

```
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(d) + theme_classic() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype=2, color='gray60') +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype=2, color='gray60') +
  geom_segment(
    aes(xend=PC1,yend=PC2, color=class), x=0,y=0,
    arrow=arrow(type='closed', angle=20, length=unit(0.02,'npc'))
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, label=name), force=6, min.segment.length = 10, seed=123
  ) +
  ylim(-0.3,0.3) + xlim(-0.3,0.3) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name='Legend Title',
    values=c('Neutral'='bisque3','Sulfated'='springgreen3','Silylated'='orange'))
```

[image]

`ggplot2` will create a legend for certain aesthetics, but they must be placed within `aes()`.  Once you do that, `ggplot2` will create the legend and automatically assign colors.  This means that if we want to create a legend for `color=`, you need to put it within `aes()`.  The interesting part is that you can put it within `aes()` anywhere in the call, or just apply to specific geom/geoms.  This allows a lot of flexibility in creating your plot.  In this case, I only want to color the arrows, so you include `color=class` within the `geom_segment()` call.  If you put it within the `ggplot()` call, it would color both the line segment as well as the text geom.

I'm also paying attention to the ordering.  We want to make sure the background dotted lines for the central axis at 0,0 are "behind" everything, so they go first.  Then the segments, and then the text geom.

The `scale_color_manual()` function is used to specify the colors for the different `d$class` values explicitly and the name of the legend.  You can also just let `ggplot2` find a palette by default, or you can specify via a palette (there are a ton of other methods to specify color).  BTW - you can also specify the name of the legend via `labs(color=...`.

Finally, I decided to use `geom_text_repel()` rather than `geom_text()`.  Since the lines go out in every direction, the "nudge" values for each text item are not going to work going in the same direction.  In other words, if you plot the text at `x=PC1, y=PC2`, it will overlap the arrowheads.  You noticed this too and applied `nudge_` values, which happens to work, but if your data was a bit different, it would not have worked.  `geom_text_repel` from the `ggrepel` package can work to do this by kind of "pushing" the text away from your points.

Comment: That's really helpful. A contribution plot is what I had in mind initially, but because it would have been to plot all the 63 variables I had, I decided to do it as this. Unless there is a way to perform a contribution plot with the most contributing as the labelled and less transparent, while the least contributing faded. THANKS!!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by contribution plot (those I have seen are basically just bar plots); however, you can plot all 63 and just highlight those that are the most contributing.    If you do want the answer to that question, it's probably best submitted as a separate question and please provide your data and a general example of what you're trying to do.  BTW - datasets are best shared by loading the dataframe in R and then copying and pasting the output of the function `dput(your.data.frame)` into your question as code.  It ensures we can recreate your dataframe easily.